# Generate list of file paths without entries for directories

Tags: bash, shell, tree, zsh

In a script of mine I need to list all files in a directory *and its subdirectories* such as can be done with `tree -if`, but I need to ignore the directories in the listing--they only need to appear in the paths of the files.  I don't see anything on the man page for `tree` for listing only files, essentially the opposite of `-d`, which lists only directories.

How can I do this?

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: Use `find -type f` instead of `tree`

Comment: @Barmar: as a matter of fact this is for use in a script, so if you want to push the issue, it _is_ about programming.  In a Venn diagram, there is a huge overlap between SO and U&L.

Comment: Is the fact that it's being used in a script relevant to the problem? Or is the answer the same if you're using the program interactively

Comment: @Barmar you could ask that about most things, perhaps virtually everything, on SO related to any shell.

Comment: It's obviously a fuzzy boundary. My answer is like the definition of pornography: I know it when I see it.

Comment: It is an inevitable result of the (in retrospect, unfortunate) decision (or series of decisions, more accurately) that the SE founders made to have separate thematic sites, unlike Quora's approach.  The idea that clean boundaries _are possible_ results in an enormous amount of wasted energy worrying about putting things in the "right" site.

Answer (score 2):

Use `find` instead of `tree`.

```
find ! -type d ! -name '.*' -print
```

`-type d` matches directories, and `!` means to exclude them. `! -name '.*'` excludes filenames that begin with `.` (hidden files).

Comment: Updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Since your question is taggeg `zsh`, here is something you can do in `zsh`:

```
ls **/*(.)
```

`**` means recursive and `(.)` at the end means only files.

If it is `bash`, you might want to try to specify `zsh` instead. Most `bash` things work in `zsh`.

Maybe I didn't get all the constraints, but if it is the case you can put them in comments and I'll refine my answer.

Update:

As mentioned in the comments, this solution will fail if the list of files is very long because extended globbing is expanded in place and therefore all the filenames will end up in the command line which has a limit. If it is the case, `find` is a safer bet. But it is always worth trying because I personally find the extended globbing easier to remember.

Comment: It's a great idea, and it'll work in the context of my script (where I have a pretty short argument list) but I quickly tested it in my current directory and got `zsh: argument list too long: ls` so it might not work for everyone in every situation.  It's certainly a much cleaner syntax than `find` 

Comment: @iconoclast extended globbing is a strong feature of zsh and the good thing is that it works for any command, they are just globbing. But indeed the side effect is that it is expanded in place on the prompt, therefore it is subject to a limit in size. It is like you typing all these names on the command line. I am glad it works in the context of your script.